# Website crashes post web.config changes

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, umbraco

I have a production website deployed on Azure VM.

During the production deployment, whenever i make the changes to the web.config, after making the changes, the website goes down from about 30min and it comes back automatically.

What is the best way to do the changes to the web.config file.

My website is running with Umbraco CMS v7.1

Please advice.

Comment: Changes to web.config mean the IIS process for your site will restart. This is normal behavior. Although 30 minutes for it to come back up again is horrible. What type of solution are you looking for?

Comment: Is it because of Umbraco caching in the website and it takes 30 mins to bring back the website? What would be first place i should be looking to avoid this

Comment: Could you not separate the cache from the application (i.e. into a key/value store like Redis) so that an app restart doesn't result in an invalidated cache?

Comment: Could you check the umbraco log files for any problems? I've been hosting Umbraco on Azure for a long time but haven't experienced this before

Answer (score 0):

You should not make changes to you `Web.config` during a production deploy. If you have different connection strings for development and production, you should be using seperate config files.

If your `Web.config` look something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <remove name="Db" />
  <add name="Db" connectionString="local database" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then you can create a `Web.Release.config` that transforms the connection string when doing a release build:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Db" connectionString="prod database" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This way your local database is used for development and your production database is used in production, without needing to update/change the `Web.config` during a deployment.

More reading on the topic:
[How to: Set Debug and Release Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx)
[How to: Transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx)